# Copying British dates into American Format

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have VBA code which selects a range of dates and inserts them into another sheet.

```
Set data = csvFile.Sheets(sheetname).Range("$A$1:$F$" & lastRow)
newPlan.Sheets(client & "_CSV").Range("$A$1:$F$" & lastRow).Value = data.Value
```

The dates are in DD/MM/YY format, and when they are inserted to the new file they are given MM/DD/YYYY format but only if the date can exist.

For example 30/05/18 will be inserted the same as there is no 30th month, but 01/05/18 will be inserted as 05/01/2018.

I don't mind what format the dates are copied as, as long as they are consistent. I can convert them to the correct format later if they are in MM/DD/YYYY format.

I tried setting number format before copying from the CSV file, but does not help:

```
csvFile.Sheets(sheetname).Range("$D$1:$D$" & lastRow).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

Comment: Have you tried "yyyy/mm/dd"?

Comment: read dates in as long and write out to formatted column or apply format after?

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear all date format in your `Range("$D$1:$D$" & lastRow)` and apply the NumberFormat method:

```
csvFile.Sheets(sheetname).Range("$D$1:$D$" & lastRow).ClearFormats
csvFile.Sheets(sheetname).Range("$D$1:$D$" & lastRow).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the Cell and make it equal to "Format (Cell, data style)".

For Example, with Row and Col being any location in a sheet:

```
sheet.Cells(Row, Col) = Format(sheet.Cells(Row, Col), "dd/mm/yyyy")
```